# Given "input date" is between two dates or not?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
Table structure
id      from(date)_field      to(date)_field      field3       field4
1         date1                    date2         something     something
2         date3                    date4         something     something
3         date5                    date6         something     something
.           .                        .               .            .
.           .                        .               .            .
```

I want to find out the top 1 row where the from(date)_field is between the user_input_date and from(date)_field.

Comment: First, store your dates in columns with a datatype of DATE. Then it will be much easier to use them with SQL

Comment: i have stored as a DATE datatype only.

Comment: @Animesh then what is the example `date1(dd-mm-yy)`? That is not DATE format

Comment: Then they are not stored in the format (dd/mm/yy). Which makes your question rather misleading.

Comment: *nearest date* before or after that input? You got two dates (`from/to`), which one to compare? Might be something simple like `inputdate between from and to`

Comment: yes, i want to compare with the 'from' field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
select t.*
from t
order by abs(datediff(fromdate, @yourdate))
limit 1;
```

More typically, you would not want the *closest* date.  You would want the row where the date is between the to and from dates.  However, you are explicitly asking for the closest.

Comment: No, I want to closest/nearest date, there may be more than one row which will be in between but i need the closest.

Comment: @Animesh . . . That is what this answer does.

Comment: okay i am trying to do this. thank you so much..

Comment: t stands for table name?

Comment: @Animesh . .  Yes, `t` is for your table.

Answer (score -1):

Use datediff and find the smallest value.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(second, fromdate, Userdate) AS DateDiff;
SELECT DATEDIFF(second, Todate, Userdate) AS DateDiff1;
```

And compare `DateDiff` and `DateDiff1` which have lowest value that would be closest one